# Nightmarejs Navegando y haciendo scrapping a multiples sitios

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Estoy tratando de automatizar 2 sitios con [NightmareJs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) todo sobre una app desktop de electron

Ejemplo:

1. Quiero ir al `sitio_1` (servicio de correo electrónico temporal) y recibir un correo electrónico.
2. Luego vaya al `sitio_2` y complete ese correo electrónico, luego envíe un formulario.
3. Luego vaya al `sitio_1` y verifique si llegó el correo electrónico
4. Analiza el mensaje de correo electrónico del `sitio_1` y busca el codigo de verificacion (otp) y lo manda al `sitio_2`
5. ir al `sitio_2` Recibe el codigo otp y lo coloca en el input para finalizar el registro.

   ........... etc

He estado viendo opciones desde la propia documentacion de nightmarejs pero dan ejemplos muy simples y basicos, alguna muestra o ejemplo parecido para poderme guiar, seria de mucha ayudo.

Hasta ahora lo que he podido conseguir ha sido hasta el `punto 3`. Pero no sabiendo como pasar despues el codigo otp

```
nightmareEmail
     .viewport(400, 600)
     .goto(PAGE_EMAIL_GENERATE)
     .wait('#mail')
     .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#mail').value)
     .then(email => {
         registerUser(email)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
         console.error('Search failed:', error);
      });

registerUser(email) {
        let name = Faker.name.findName()
        let password = Faker.internet.password()
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Registrando')
        nightmareRegister
            .clearCache()
            .viewport(400,600)
            .goto(PAGE_FOR_REGISTER)
            .type('input[name=customerName', name)
            .type('input[name=email]', email)
            .type('input[name=password]', password)
            .type('input[name=passwordCheck]', password)
            .click('input#continue[type=submit]')
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            .then(() => console.log('Done!'))
    }
```

Comment: Desconozco cómo hacer ello, sin embargo te doy una probable alternativa: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/